# How to get recommendation letters from professors when you have only worked with PhDs?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I did my masters in Germany and there we rarely work with professors directly.
Now I am applying for a PhD and need recommendation letters from professors.

How should proceed here? I already asked a PhD student if he provide me a letter and let it be approved by the professor. But I am not sure if this is the correct procedure.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common in Germany that a professor will be willing to write a good recommendation letter if you've worked with their PhD students extensively and they can endorse you. I would just ask the professor directly and mention your history of working with their PhD students.

Comment: In the US, I've also had the experience of a PhD student writing a paragraph about the recommendee, and then the professor incorporating this into the rest of their letter. Would this also be normal in Germany?

Comment: Speaking from my personal experience and that of friends and acquaintances, there seems to be no one clear way the process of writing a recommendation letter goes. The professor might meet with the student and then write everything themselves, a PhD student/postdoc from the professor's lab might take part in the writing process, or the student will write a draft themselves, and everything in between